# Capture all objects with specific data-toggle via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I a using `jQuery 3.5.1` and I have the following HTML element in my DOM:

```
<a href="#top" data-toggle="sidebar-collapse" class="...">
```

I try to capture it via the following expression:

```
$('[data-toggle=sidebar-collapse]')
```

This one returns an empty list and I am wondering what I am missing here. The original examples comes from the link below: I copied the source into my project but no success. Thank you for your help!

https://www.codeply.com/p/1TlcDLPfiE

P.S. In the original called its called 'sidebar-colapse' with one 'l'. I fixed this in my examples in the JS and html file.

Comment: The fact there's no find in text option on codeply is a serious issue. When I console log `$(["data-toggle=sidebar-collapse"])` I get a result, though. Are you getting nothing?

Comment: I just realized, the js is executed probably too early

Comment: That will *definitely* do it. So you got it sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing [quotes in your attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), this is how it should be:

```js
console.log($('[data-toggle="sidebar-collapse"]'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#top" data-toggle="sidebar-collapse" class="...">
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately still 0 :-( `$('[data-toggle="sidebar-collapse"]').length` returns `0`

Comment: I know what happened here! The js is executed too early, so before the DOM :-(

Comment: I think there it's loaded with a document ready and therefore fun. I agree the codeply page doesn't make it easy to understand what is executed when

Comment: @DanielStephens, I just added $(document).ready and it worked, sorry for late response, but the tool used (codeplay) is too much cluttered with colors :P